Deciphering words in a report from canonical visitation from 1596
I recently started working on deciphering an detailed report from canonical visitation of my home village which took place in 1596.
Most of the text is clear to me, but there are a few words which are e.g. abbreviated or does not make sense to me – therefore I ask for help:)
I attach scans of the report with words marked either orange (which I cannot decipher) or violet (which I deciphered, but which do not make fully sense to me).
Here are a few remarks to the marked words: 
Ad. 1) I thought it's harasio, but it seems such a word does not exist in Latin. 
Ad. 2) I think here the writer tried to spell some Polish word, but szerzÿnek does not make sense to me. Maybe it would help if I'd know the precise meaning of tobalia (could it be something related to tobalea vel pectinarium?). 
Ad. 5) I thought there should also be the number (e.g. "100 floren[orum]"), but maybe there was only "[unus] floren[us]" in the treasury? 
Ad. 6) I think it might be the name of some book, but in none of other reports from similar canonical visitations had I seen any other book between librum Agendorum and Graduale. 
Ad. 10) I deciphered this word as offi[ci]at[u]r, i.e. celebrating [a mass].



